# String is not recognised as used and is highlighted in grey despite everything being set public

Tags: android, json, string, arraylist

I have an activity in which layout I have X checkboxes and X TextView.

Through "setText()" I am filling the TextViews with text parsed through JSON in a complex form (several values from several columns plus static text).

I would like to convert this answer in a string to be later added to an Arraylist but it turns out null (I think because of the quotation marks).

this is the average text I am parsing and "setText"ing:

```
    public void showJSON(String response){
    String One="";
    String Two="";
    String Three = "";
    String Four = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response4);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        One = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_One);
        Two = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Two);
        Three = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Three);
        Four = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Four);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView.setText("One:\t"+One+"\nTwo:\t" +Two+ "\nThree:    "+ Three+"\nFour:\t"+Four);


}
```

I tried newString = String.valueOf("One:\t"+One+"\nTwo:\t" +Two+ "\nThree:  "+ Three+"\nFour:\t"+Four); right after the setText, but it returns a null.

With a String newString = ""; it also becomes a problem as I have quotation marks in the code as well.

It goes without saying that both String newString; and TextView textView; are declared at the beginning.

Any guess?

Complete code is as following

```
public class Popup1  extends Activity {

public TextView textViewResult;
public String newString;
public ArrayList<String> builder = new ArrayList<String>();

public CheckBox check;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup1);

    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);


    final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkView(checkBox1, "holacheck", newString);

    isChecked(checkBox1, "holacheck");

    getData();
}



public void checkView (final CheckBox view, final String key, final String newString) {
    view.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (view.isChecked()) {
                KeySaver.saveShare(Popup1.this, key, view.isChecked());
                builder.add((String.valueOf(newString)));
                builder.add("\n");

            } else {
                KeySaver.removeKey(Popup1.this, key);

            }


        }
    });
}



public void isChecked(final CheckBox view, String key){
    if(view != null){
        if(KeySaver.isExist(Popup1.this, key)){
            view.setChecked(KeySaver.getBoolSavedShare(Popup1.this, key));
        }else{
            view.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

public void getData() {

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();


            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Popup1.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
public void showJSON(String response){
    String One="";
    String Two="";
    String Three = "";
    String Four = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        One = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_One);
        Two = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Two);
        Three = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Three);
        Four = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_Four);



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("One:\t" + One + "\nTwo:\t" + Two + "\nThree:\t" + Three + "\nFour:\t" + Four);

    newString = String.valueOf("One:"+One+"Two:" +Two+ "Three:"+ Three+"Four:"+Four);

}


}



@Override
public void finish() {
    String risultato = builder.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    // Prepare data intent
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("result", risultato);
    setResult(1, data );
    super.finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newString` is null the first time you access it in `onCreate()` in the line:

```
checkView(checkBox1, "holacheck", newString);
```

This is because your data hadn't been retrieved yet at that point.

Make `checkBox1` a class field, and move the `checkView()` call to the end of the `showJSON()` method.

```
private CheckBox checkBox1;
...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    isChecked(checkBox1, "holacheck");
    getData();
}

public void showJSON(String response){
    ...
    textViewResult.setText("One:\t" + One + "\nTwo:\t" + Two + "\nThree:\t" + Three + "\nFour:\t" + Four);
    newString = String.valueOf("One:"+One+"Two:" +Two+ "Three:"+ Three+"Four:"+Four);
    checkView(checkBox1, "holacheck", newString);
}
```